# Why is this mail going straight to SPAM box?

Tags: php, email

I am using the following script to send mail

```
<?
extract($_POST);
$subject = "Feedback from ".$name." (".$email.", Ph: ".$phone.")";
$mail = @mail($send,$subject,$content);
if($mail) { echo "Your feedback has been sent"; }
else { echo "We are sorry for the inconvienience, but we could not send your feedback now."; }
?>
```

But this is always ending up in the spam Folder. Why?

Comment: Most spamfilters enter headers in the mail why they consider it spam, what do those say?

Comment: Check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html for extra informations about sending email. Its more of a lecture than a solution.

Comment: That should be `Your feedback has been sent.  Thank you.`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are all mails sent via php's mail() go to spam box but not mails sent directly from the domain's account ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032286/why-are-all-mails-sent-via-phps-mail-go-to-spam-box-but-not-mails-sent-directl)

Comment: Do you know what a reverse PTR record is? Do you have one?

Comment: @SLaks, Corrected, but how is this related to my question

Comment: I assume that you want your website to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use headers while you send mail, to prove that the mail arrives from a genuine source and not a bot.

Try this!

```
<?
  extract($_POST);
  $subject = "Feedback from ".$name." (".$email.", Ph: ".$phone.")";
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From:'.$email."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email;
  $mail = @mail($feedback,$subject,$content,$headers);
  if($mail) { echo "Your feedback is send"; }
  else { echo "We are sorry for the inconvienience, but we could not send your feedback now."; }
?>
```

Comment: Beware of email header injection: http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html